# set d3 zoom scaleExtent to positive values

Tags: d3.js, zooming

Well, first of all, [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/18/) to illustrate what I would like to ask

So I am trying to implement a zoom behaviour. I managed to limit the zooming by setting a translate to the zoom function, (which I don't really quite understand, Just got it from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385490/d3-graph-with-limited-zoom)), and a scaleExtent([1,10]) on the zoom behaviour

So this is the zoom behavior:

```
  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                     .x(xScale)
                     .y(yScale)
                     .scaleExtent([1, 10])
                     .on("zoom", zoomed)
```

and this is the zoomed function:

```
zoomed = ->

t = zoom.translate()
s = zoom.scale()

tx = t[0]
ty = t[1]

tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(w * (1-s), t[0]))
ty = Math.min(0, Math.max((h-padding) * (1-s), t[1]))

zoom.translate([tx, ty])

svgContainer.select("g.x.axis").call xAxis
svgContainer.select("g.y.axis").call yAxis

svgContainer.selectAll("line.matched_peak")
                        .attr("x1", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                        .attr("y1", h - padding)
                        .attr("x2", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                        .attr("y2", (d) -> return yScale(d.m_intensity) )
```

However, setting the scaleExtent to

`.scaleExtent([1, 10])` ,

makes that one particular point with a value of 1 in the y scale is never going to be displayed (first one on the left in the jsfiddle). 
But setting

`.scaleExtent([0, 10])`

disables the limit to zoom, and the user may zoom and pan below 0 in the y axis.

Also tried `.scaleExtent([0.1, 10])` but this also allows zoom and pan below 0.

So How could I allow zoom only to positive values from 0 (including a value of 1) ?

And what function can be used to avoid the lines show beyond the axis? Is not that implicit when I use the translate function in the zoom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scale proceeds in a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) -- that is, the scale step before 1 is not 0, but 0.5. Limiting your scale extent to

```
.scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
```

should do what you want. I've also added [`.nice()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_nice) to your scale definitions to get round numbers at the ends.

As for the clipping, no, this is not implicit in the translation. You need to clip explicitly using a [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), which in your case can be defined as follows.

```
cp = svgContainer.append("defs").append("clipPath").attr("id", "cp")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", padding)
        .attr("y", padding)
        .attr("width", w - 2 * padding)
        .attr("height", h - 2 * padding)
```

All you then need to do is use it when adding the elements:

```
msBars = svgContainer.selectAll('line.matched_peak')
                    .data(jsonFragmentIons)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("clip-path", "url(#cp)")
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/19/).

Comment: I did not know about clip path! Works great! As forthe scaleExtent, using 0.5 restricts panning below 0 but it is still possible to zoom out to values below 0, why is that?

Comment: Hey @Lars, how did you learn all that stuff about d3.js? I am having some trouble to learn, especially this zoom things, just by looking at examples on bostock and/or questions on SO. Is there any good tutorial? I know alignedleft, but that does not cover some topics like zooming

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the zoom -- zoom levels below 0 don't make sense, where are you getting those? And there are lots of tutorials linked on the D3 website that are worth taking a look at. Don't know of any specific one for zooming.

Comment: I mean zooming out (with mouse wheel) makes the scale on the y axis to go below 0, that is what I meant in the first question

Comment: Well in that case `.scaleExtent([1, 10])` should be fine -- http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/20/ This refers to the scale factor of the graph, not to any particular axis/scale.

Comment: I got it alright now, my problem was that I was .nice() ing to range instead of domain. Thanks man