# d3 limit zoom level for time axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

My code is below for zooming on time X-axis. I want to set a limit in between time should zoom in or out i.e. upper limit and lower limit of time.
I've tried to put boundaries value in zoomed function which was suggested in this [d3 graph with limited zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385490/d3-graph-with-limited-zoom) thread. but it isn't working.

```js
var x = d3.time
  .scale()
  .domain([start_date, end_date])
  .range([0, width]);

var zoom = d3.behavior
  .zoom()
  .x(x)
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg = d3
  .select("#chart" + k)
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  svg.selectAll(".line").remove();

  makeBackground();

  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  d3.select(".x.axis.top").call(xAxisTop);

  svg.select(".x.grid").call(
    make_x_axis()
      .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat("")
  );
  svg.selectAll(".circle-path").remove();
  d3.selectAll(".trainTag").remove();
  drawPaths();
  drawCircle(x, y, chartBody, trainData[0]);
}
```

anyone have any other solution in order to set the zoom level may be for next and previous 2 hours.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In d3 v4 the d3.zoom().scaleExtent allows to limit the *user* in zooming beyond the given boundaries (programmatically it may be set beyond though). These are given as factors, not as time-range. But you can surely calculate the factors yourself, using the known start- and end-time of the scale:

```
const minTimeMilli = 20000; // do not allow zooming beyond displaying 20 seconds
const maxTimeMilli = 6.3072e+11; // approx 20 years

const widthMilli = endTime - startTime;

const minScaleFactor = widthMilli / maxTimeMilli;
const maxScaleFactor = widthMilli / minTimeMilli;

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([minScaleFactor, maxScaleFactor])
```